# Quotes in user string input in C++

Tags: c++, string

VERY basic question here...from a school project in an intro C++ class

Working with classmates on a program in Replit, I have no issues if a user includes quotation marks as part of their input

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
    
using namespace std;
    
int main() {
    
    std::string name;  
       
    std::cout << "Enter your name:";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    
    std::cout << name;
    
}
```

This works fine in Replit if the user input is something like `Billy "Bob" Smith`.

But with the XCode compiler that the school uses in conjunction with its autograder, instead of printing out `Billy "Bob" Smith` I get `Billy`  and then some kind of control character...looks like a question mark in a box.

One of the test cases for the program includes a name with a quoted nickname in the middle, so I'm guessing this is a "gotcha".

Is there something other than std:getline that should be used to handle non-alpha characters in string input?

Comment: I can't reproduce it either....except in the output from the autograder that keeps failing the test case where there are quotations in the user input....

Comment: I bet the autograder file got opened in some tools like Word and the `"` got replaced with some fancy Unicode symbol. https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html probably outside your control

Comment: It's likely a unicode character which looks like standard quote. You can safeguard against that by using ynicode support

Comment: More likely than not, the input contains some Unicode characters that look like ASCII quotes. Who is providing the test case? Can you talk to them? Where exactly do you see the weird characters? Can you obtain the output file, make a hex dump of it, and post it here? Does the grading system downgrade your solution because of this problem? Do other students have the same problem?

Comment: I'll go to the prof's office hours tonight and see what I can find out.  The autograder shows me expected and actual output for test cases the prof generated.  Everything works fine except the case where the expected output is a name with a "quoted" nickname in the middle, where my actual output shows a control character and then stops...

Comment: "The autograder shows me" Does this mean you have to go to some kind of web page to see the results? Also, does it show you the *input*?

Comment: Is that you entire program? Or do you process that `name` somehow?

Comment: That was just a minimal example.  The entire program plays three rounds of rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock.  It just passes that string around.  The autograder is a website where you upload your source file and then you get a report that shows expected output on the left side and your actual output on the right side...it's a pain since a stray newline can throw the whole thing off, but I guess I wouldn't want to manually grade 250 programs either...

Comment: How do you know there is a problem in *this* program? Did you get the autograder grade it? If you have unlimited attempts, you can just upload it (or better a program that does the same thing in a loop, i e. copies the entire standard input to the standard output) and see if you get any weird characters.

Comment: This is just a minimal example where I gathered the input the same way I do in the real program.  In the real one there are two names, stored in `name1` and `name2` and they get passed around a bunch.  Eventually the name of the winner gets printed.  I could not submit THIS program to the autograder...the assignment is set up to be very specific in terms of function names, which functions call which others, etc.  I only have 4 attempts with the autograder and I have used two of them, so I'm hesitant to burn another until I feel like I've actually done something to address it.

Comment: Well obviously you should not burn your attempts, better book time with your prof.

Comment: @jerH The code shown is perfectly fine, so the problem has to be a flaw in the autograder itself.